# Scene Kit Rotation - rotating around X and Y axis only, causing Z rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, scenekit, quaternions

I am trying to control the orientation of a box in Scene Kit (iOS) using gestures. I am using the translation in x and y to update the x and y rotation of the SCNNode.

After a long search I have realised that x and y rotation will always lead to z rotation, thanks to this excellent post: [gamedev stack exchange: I'm rotating an object on two axes, so why does it keep twisting around the third axis?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir)

So I am trying to get the z rotation causes, and then remove this from my object by applying the inverse quaternion however when I rotate the object 90 deg around x, and then 90 deg around Y it behaves VERY weirdly.

It is almost behaving as it is in gimbal lock, but I did not think that using quaternion in the way that I am would cause gimbal lock in this way.

I am sure it is something I am missing, or perhaps I am not able to remove the z rotation in this way.

Thanks!

The code I am using to rotate during pan gesture is:

```
@objc func panGestureQ(_ gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            guard let boxNode = boxNode else { return }
            
            let translation = gestureRecognize.translation(in: gestureRecognize.view!)
            let angleY = Float(translation.x) * 0.003
            let angleX = Float(translation.y) * 0.003
            
            let rotationX = simd_quaternion(angleX, simd_float3(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            let rotationY = simd_quaternion(angleY, simd_float3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
            
            let combined = rotationX * rotationY
            
            let tempNode = SCNNode()
            tempNode.simdOrientation = boxNode.simdOrientation
            let zBefore = tempNode.eulerAngles.z
            
            tempNode.simdOrientation =  combined * tempNode.simdOrientation
            
            let zAfter = tempNode.eulerAngles.z
            let zDiff = zAfter - zBefore
            
            let rotationZ = simd_quaternion(zDiff, simd_float3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1))

            boxNode.simdOrientation =  rotationZ.inverse * combined * boxNode.simdOrientation
            
            gestureRecognize.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gestureRecognize.view)
            
           
        }
```

I have added a video of the strange behaviour [here](https://github.com/marcusraty/RotationExample/blob/main/Example.MP4)

And the code example is [here](https://github.com/marcusraty/RotationExample)

Comment: Your code (which should be embedded in your question, not linked off-site) uses Euler angles. Those are explicitly gimbals, which is why you're getting gimbal-like behaviour. Do I understand correctly that you want the cube to always rotate relative to the current view, but remove the "twist" so whatever is currently the "top" face doesn't lean left or right on the screen? That motion is not consistently stored in the z Euler angle component (nor any component — I tell folks not to do math on individual angles in these triplets because they're so good at misleading intuition).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. I have embedded the code which rotates the object during gestures. 

If you image an phone in portrait orientation, scene kit has world coordinates z towards you (out the phone), x to the right side of the screen, and y to the top of the phone. As the user drags their finger I would like the object to rotate about itself in terms of x and y. It is the objects z rotate I would like to controls/stop.


I must has misunderstood the way to do this, because I thought that I could read the z Euler and remove the z rotate this way